# Clarification of VB Script Program to Zip Files Error Message

Tags: vbscript, zip

Below is a small VB script that I believe should zip files in a folder.
I am new to VB script.

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items
objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

I found the script here. [Batch file script to zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485419/batch-file-script-to-zip-files)

I run the script with the following

```
CScript zipt.vbs ..\AFolder AFolder.zip
```

I get the following error:

```
zipIt.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required
: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)'
```

`..\AFolder` is not empty. The zip file is created and is empty.

Debugging the script, the error is on this line.

```
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items
```

What does the error message mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line arguments - object required: 'objshell.NameSpace(...)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713740/command-line-arguments-object-required-objshell-namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713740/command-line-arguments-object-required-objshell-namespace), try this:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InputFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
ZipFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(1))
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items
objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

To clarify, the script essentially didn't know what "AFolder.zip" was so it needs the entire, absolute path.